# Creating temporary file from C program in Linux mint

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc

What is the easiest way to create a temporary file from C program in Linux?

We can either call system function and use mktemp

```
system("TMPFILENAME=$(mktemp tmp.XXXXXXXX)");
```

or we can use function

`mkstemp` function or we can use `tmpfile` of `tmpnam` functions.

Comment: Please don't. Use `tmpnam()` or `tmpfile()` instead.

Comment: maybe you should do it in C actually? http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktemp

Comment: Each system call invokes a new instance of the shell. You'd have to put all your commands in one shell invocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this. You *should* be using the `mkstemp` function. Here's an example that prints the name of the file like you want along with other information:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    // buffer to hold the temporary file name
    char nameBuff[32];
    // buffer to hold data to be written/read to/from temporary file
    char buffer[24];
    int filedes = -1,count=0;

    // memset the buffers to 0
    memset(nameBuff,0,sizeof(nameBuff));
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));

    // Copy the relevant information in the buffers
    strncpy(nameBuff,"/tmp/myTmpFile-XXXXXX",21);
    strncpy(buffer,"Hello World",11);

    errno = 0;
    // Create the temporary file, this function will replace the 'X's
    filedes = mkstemp(nameBuff);

    // Call unlink so that whenever the file is closed or the program exits
    // the temporary file is deleted
    unlink(nameBuff);

    if(filedes<1)
    {
        printf("\n Creation of temp file failed with error [%s]\n",strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Temporary file [%s] created\n", nameBuff);
    }
}
```

For a reference of the function look [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkstemp.html).